How to use css grayscale() in emotion/styled?
I use react-leaflet to show map. I wanted to make a openstreetmap with grayscale. This answer shows I should use css grayscale function https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/143#issuecomment-224057041
but I use emotion/styled to style elements and I dont know how to apply grayscale here
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import { FC } from "react";
import {TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";

const MapTile = styled(TileLayer)(() => ({
  ".leaflet-tile-pane": {
    WebkitFilter: grayscale("100%"),
    filter: grayscale("100%")
  }
}));


any ideas how to do it?
